# Kendo UI Grid - Columns in GroupHeader

Tags: kendo-ui, grid

I'm working with a grid that has a lot of boolean data on it's model, so I've got a lot of checkboxes (through a client template) on my grid. At the top of the grid, I have also (in the column's headerTemplate) got checkboxes that basically set/clear all the checkboxes for the same column throughout the grid - and all is just peachy...

However, what I would really like to do is to also have checkboxes in Group Headers (groupings), allowing the user to set/clear all the values for that column within that group.

Whilst I can do this as just a sequence of checkboxes in a group header template, one after the other, it just looks bad. What I really need is to be able to position the checkboxes in the Group Header so as they appear "in line" with the checkboxes from the actual model items.

Any ideas anyone?

Martin.

Comment: You can try...know the grouping number and the width of the grouping icon cell plus the width of your columns you could calculate it as (GroupingCount * GroupingIconCellWidth) + RunningColumnWidths + ColumnIndexWidth or something in js. However, how will you handle column width changes or parent container width changes for columns with NO widths. There is no template for this so it is probably not supported.

Comment: Thanks for the idea... I think, unfortunately, this is going to result in a move away from Kendo in the next phase of the project :(